# Interspire shopping cart PHP error

Tags: php

I am using interspire shopping cart version 3.5
when uploading product image following error occur  Undefined index: UPLOADHANDLER_ERR_MOVE_NOT_WRITABLE
 Please explain how to remove this error
ISC_LOG->HandlePHPErrors on line no 138

/lib/uploadhandler.php  ISC_LOG->HandlePHPErrors
 on line 138

```
/admin/includes/classes/class.product.image.php UploadHandlerFile->moveAs
```

on line 99

```
/includes/classes/class.product.image.php   ISC_ADMIN_PRODUCT_IMAGE->remoteNewImageUpload on line 24
/includes/classes/class.remote.php  ISC_ADMIN_PRODUCT_IMAGE->routeRemoteRequest on line 29
/admin/remote.php   ISC_ADMIN_REMOTE->HandleToDo on line 18




 <?php

if (!defined('UPLOAD_ERR_EXTENSION')) {
    // introduced in 5.1.2
    define('UPLOAD_ERR_EXTENSION', 8);
}

class UploadHandlerException extends Exception { }
class UploadHandlerFileException extends UploadHandlerException { }

class UploadHandlerProcessException extends UploadHandlerException { }
class UploadHandlerProcessPostSizeException extends UploadHandlerProcessException { }
class UploadHandlerProcessNoInputException extends UploadHandlerProcessException { }

class UploadHandlerFileMoveException extends UploadHandlerFileException { }
class UploadHandlerFileMoveExistsException extends UploadHandlerFileMoveException { }
class UploadHandlerFileMoveNotWritableException extends UploadHandlerFileMoveException { }

/**
* Class for storing information about an uploaded file. Returned as a result of the various 'get' file methods in the UploadHandler class.
*
*/
class UploadHandlerFile {

    /**
     * Name of upload field in HTML form
     *
     * @var string
     */
    public $fieldName;

    /**
     * Name of uploaded file from client system
     *
     * @var string
     */
    public $name;

    /**
     * MIME type of uploaded file
     *
     * @var string
     */
    public $type;

    /**
     * Full path and filename of temporary uploaded file
     *
     * @var string
     */
    public $tmp_name;

    /**
     * Error code of uploaded file, if any
     *
     * @var int
     */
    public $error;

    /**
     * Size of uploaded file, in bytes
     *
     * @var int
     */
    public $size;

    /**
     * Indicates if the file has been moved out of the temp storage.
     *
     * @var bool
     */
    private $moved = false;

    /**
    *
    * @param string $fieldName Name of uploaded field in HTML form
    * @param string $name Name of uploaded file from client system
    * @param string $type MIME type of uploaded file
    * @param string $tmp_name Full path and filename of temporary uploaded file
    * @param int $error Error code of uploaded file, if any
    * @param int $size Size of uploaded file, in bytes
    * @return UploadHandlerFile
    */
    public function __construct ($fieldName, $name, $type, $tmp_name, $error, $size)
    {
        $this->fieldName = $fieldName;
        $this->name = $name;
        $this->type = $type;
        $this->tmp_name = $tmp_name;
        $this->error = $error;
        $this->size = $size;
    }

    /**
     * Attempts to moves this uploaded file to the given destination folder, automatically using the client-provided filename.
     *
     * @param string $destination Folder to move the file to
     * @param bool $overwrite Optional. Default true. If true, any existing destination file will be overwritten. If false, this will throw UploadHandlerFileMoveExistsException if the destination file exists.
     * @return bool Returns true on success, otherwise false.
     * @throws UploadHandlerFileMoveExistsException If the destination file exists and $overwrite is false.
     */
    public function move ($destination, $overwrite = true)
    {
        //  remove trailing slashes in the destination folder
        $destination = rtrim($destination, '\/');

        return $this->moveAs($destination . '/' . $this->name);
    }

    /**
     * Attempted to move this uploaded file to the given destination folder with the given filename
     *
     * @param $destination Folder to move the file to
     * @param bool $overwrite Optional. Default true. If true, any existing destination file will be overwritten. If false, this will throw UploadHandlerFileMoveExistsException if the destination file exists.
     * @return bool Returns true if the file was moved otherwise false if the file was already moved or if is_uploaded_file check returns false. If a move was attempted but failed an exception will be thrown.
     * @throws UploadHandlerFileMoveExistsException If the destination file exists and $overwrite is false.
     * @throws UploadHandlerFileMoveNotWritableException If the destination file exists and is not writable.
     */
    public function moveAs ($destination, $overwrite = true)
    {
        if ($this->moved || !is_uploaded_file($this->tmp_name)) {
            return false;
        }

        if (file_exists($destination)) {
            if (!$overwrite) {
                throw new UploadHandlerFileMoveExistsException(sprintf(UploadHandler::$i18n['UPLOADHANDLER_ERR_MOVE_EXISTS'], $this->tmp_name, $destination));
            }

            if (!is_writable($destination)) {
                throw new UploadHandlerFileMoveNotWritableException(sprintf(UploadHandler::$i18n['UPLOADHANDLER_ERR_MOVE_NOT_WRITABLE'], $this->tmp_name, $destination));
            }
        }

        $result = @move_uploaded_file($this->tmp_name, $destination);
        if (!$result) {
            // checks are performed above to avoid this but move_uploaded_file can still fail since the calls are not atomic
            throw new UploadHandlerFileMoveNotWritableException(sprintf(UploadHandler::$i18n['UPLOADHANDLER_ERR_MOVE_NOT_WRITABLE'], $this->tmp_name, $destination));
        }

        $this->moved = true;
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the extension of the uploaded file based on the client-side filename. Files with no extensions will return a blank string, files such as ".htaccess" will return "htaccess".
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getExtension ()
    {
        //  reverse the string, find the text before the first (formerly last) dot and return it
        $reversed = strrev($this->name);
        $dot = strpos($reversed, '.', 0);
        if ($dot === false || $dot === 0) {
            //  no dot or dot is at end of filename
            return '';
        }

        //  reverse the extension and return it
        return strrev(substr($reversed, 0, $dot));
    }

    /**
     * Determines if the file was uploaded OK according to the error code.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function getSuccess ()
    {
        return ($this->error === 0);
    }

    /**
     *
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getErrorMessage ()
    {
        $messages = array(
            UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE     => 'UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE',
            UPLOAD_ERR_FORM_SIZE    => 'UPLOAD_ERR_FORM_SIZE',
            UPLOAD_ERR_PARTIAL      => 'UPLOAD_ERR_PARTIAL',
            UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE      => 'UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE',
            UPLOAD_ERR_NO_TMP_DIR   => 'UPLOAD_ERR_NO_TMP_DIR',
            UPLOAD_ERR_CANT_WRITE   => 'UPLOAD_ERR_CANT_WRITE',
            UPLOAD_ERR_EXTENSION    => 'UPLOAD_ERR_EXTENSION',
        );

        if (!isset($messages[$this->error])) {
            return '';
        }

        return sprintf(UploadHandler::$i18n[$messages[$this->error]], $this->fieldName, $this->type, $this->tmp_name, $this->error, $this->size, $this->getExtension());
    }
}

/**
* Generic file upload handler class with temporary file management, exception throwing and language-based error information
*
*/
class UploadHandler {

    /**
     * Whether or not uploaded files have been processed yet.
     *
     * @var bool
     */
    protected static $_processed = false;

    /**
     * Default language text that can be changed by the app using this lib.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    public static $i18n;

    /**
     * Content length specified in the POST request.
     *
     * @var int
     */
    public static $contentLength;

    /**
     * Max post size specified in php.ini stored as a number in bytes
     *
     * @var int
     */
    public static $maxPostSize;

    /**
     * Max post size specified in php.ini stored as a number in bytes
     *
     * @var int
     */
    public static $uploadMaxFilesize;

    /**
     * Max uploadable file size based on max POST size and max upload file size
     *
     * @var int
     */
    public static $maxUploadSize;

    /**
     * Storage for data about files that have been uploaded. Array will contain a set of UploadHandlerFile instances.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    public static $files;

    /**
     * Takes a php.ini-like bytes-size string such as 2M and converts it to a number. G, M and K each represent a unit of 1024 bytes: http://php.net/ini_get
     *
     * @param string $val The value to convert
     * @return int The result in bytes
     */
    public static function iniBytes ($val)
    {
        $val = trim($val);
        $scale = strtolower($val[strlen($val) - 1]);

        $val = intval($val);
        switch ($scale) {
            case 'g':
                $val *= 1024;

            case 'm':
                $val *= 1024;

            case 'k':
                $val *= 1024;
        }

        return $val;
    }

    /**
     * Processes server and $_FILE info relating to uploads to produce usable info. Assigns all gathered data to class variables which are accessible via public methods.
     *
     * @return void
     * @throws UploadHandlerProcessPostSizeException If the posted data size exceeds the maximum post size defined by php configuration
     * @throws UploadHandlerProcessNoInputException If no files were uploaded
     */
    public static function processUploads ()
    {
        if (self::$_processed) {
            return;
        }

        self::$_processed = true;

        self::$files = array();

        if (self::$contentLength >= self::$maxPostSize) {
            //  post length exceeds maximum post length ini directive - impossible for php to parse uploaded files because $_FILES is empty
            throw new UploadHandlerProcessPostSizeException(sprintf(self::$i18n['UPLOADHANDLER_ERR_PROCESS_POST_SIZE'], self::$contentLength, self::$maxPostSize));
        }

        if (empty($_FILES)) {
            //  no files uploaded
            throw new UploadHandlerProcessNoInputException(self::$i18n['UPLOADHANDLER_ERR_PROCESS_NO_INPUT']);
        }

        foreach ($_FILES as $fieldName => $field) {

            if (is_array($field['name'])) {
                //  input field that uses [] in it's name

                self::$files[$fieldName] = array();

                foreach ($field['name'] as $index => $ignoreThisValue) {
                    $name = $field['name'][$index];
                    $type = $field['type'][$index];
                    $tmp_name = $field['tmp_name'][$index];
                    $error = intval($field['error'][$index]);
                    $size = intval($field['size'][$index]);

                    $file = new UploadHandlerFile($fieldName, $name, $type, $tmp_name, $error, $size);

                    self::$files[$fieldName][] = $file;
                }

            } else {
                //  single input field
                $name = $field['name'];
                $type = $field['type'];
                $tmp_name = $field['tmp_name'];
                $error = intval($field['error']);
                $size = intval($field['size']);

                $file = new UploadHandlerFile($fieldName, $name, $type, $tmp_name, $error, $size);

                self::$files[$fieldName] = array($file);
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Returns a flat list of all uploaded files; whether successful or not
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public static function getAllFiles ()
    {
        self::processUploads();

        $return = array();
        foreach (self::$files as $field => $files) {
            foreach ($files as $file) {
                $return[] = $file;
            }
        }
        return $return;
    }

    /**
     * Returns only a list of files that were uploaded successfully
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public static function getUploadedFiles ()
    {
        self::processUploads();

        $return = array();
        foreach (self::$files as $field => $files) {
            foreach ($files as $file) {
                if ($file->getSuccess()) {
                    $return[] = $file;
                }
            }
        }
        return $return;
    }

    /**
     * Returns only a list of files that were not uploaded successfully
     *
     * @param bool $includeEmpty Optional. Default false. Set to true to include empty file upload fields as errors.
     * @return array
     */
    public static function getErrorFiles ($includeEmpty = false)
    {
        self::processUploads();

        $return = array();
        foreach (self::$files as $field => $files) {
            foreach ($files as $file) {
                if (!$includeEmpty && $file->error == UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE) {
                    continue;
                }

                if (!$file->getSuccess()) {
                    $return[] = $file;
                }
            }
        }
        return $return;
    }
}

//  statically set default language vars - an app that needs to customize messages can do so after including this class (only needs to happen once)

UploadHandler::$i18n = array(
    'UPLOADHANDLER_ERR_PROCESS_POST_SIZE'   => 'POST size of %1$d bytes exceeds the limit set in php.ini#post_max_size of %2$d bytes.',
    'UPLOADHANDLER_ERR_PROCESS_NO_INPUT'    => 'No file input fields were detected in the POST request.',
    'UPLOADHANDLER_ERR_MOVE_EXISTS'         => 'Could not move uploaded file "%1$s" to "%2$s" as the destination file already exists and the overwrite option was not set.',
    'UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE'                   => 'The uploaded file exceeds the upload_max_filesize directive in php.ini.',
    'UPLOAD_ERR_FORM_SIZE'                  => 'The uploaded file exceeds the MAX_FILE_SIZE directive that was specified in the HTML form.',
    'UPLOAD_ERR_PARTIAL'                    => 'The uploaded file was only partially uploaded.',
    'UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE'                    => 'No file was uploaded.',
    'UPLOAD_ERR_NO_TMP_DIR'                 => 'Missing a temporary folder.',
    'UPLOAD_ERR_CANT_WRITE'                 => 'Failed to write file to disk.',
    'UPLOAD_ERR_EXTENSION'                  => 'File upload stopped by extension.',
);

//  statically set some values that do not change throughout the lifetime of a request

UploadHandler::$contentLength = (int)@$_SERVER['CONTENT_LENGTH'];
UploadHandler::$maxPostSize = UploadHandler::iniBytes(ini_get('post_max_size'));

// store this for informational purposes only - php upload support will internally deny uploads which are over this size but client-side code can use this to advise of file size limits
UploadHandler::$uploadMaxFilesize = UploadHandler::iniBytes(ini_get('upload_max_filesize'));

// the lowest of both maxPostSize and uploadMaxFile size determines the maximum size of a single file upload (may not be accurate to the byte since there's some POST overhead if max POST size happens to be smaller than max file size)
UploadHandler::$maxUploadSize = min(UploadHandler::$uploadMaxFilesize, UploadHandler::$maxPostSize);
```

Comment: include the code, not just the error!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try replacing it with this code:

```
<?php

if (!defined('UPLOAD_ERR_EXTENSION')) {
    // introduced in 5.1.2
    define('UPLOAD_ERR_EXTENSION', 8);
}

class UploadHandlerException extends Exception { }
class UploadHandlerFileException extends UploadHandlerException { }

class UploadHandlerProcessException extends UploadHandlerException { }
class UploadHandlerProcessPostSizeException extends UploadHandlerProcessException { }
class UploadHandlerProcessNoInputException extends UploadHandlerProcessException { }

class UploadHandlerFileMoveException extends UploadHandlerFileException { }
class UploadHandlerFileMoveExistsException extends UploadHandlerFileMoveException { }
class UploadHandlerFileMoveNotWritableException extends UploadHandlerFileMoveException { }

/**
* Class for storing information about an uploaded file. Returned as a result of the various 'get' file methods in the UploadHandler class.
*
*/
class UploadHandlerFile {

    /**
     * Name of upload field in HTML form
     *
     * @var string
     */
    public $fieldName;

    /**
     * Name of uploaded file from client system
     *
     * @var string
     */
    public $name;

    /**
     * MIME type of uploaded file
     *
     * @var string
     */
    public $type;

    /**
     * Full path and filename of temporary uploaded file
     *
     * @var string
     */
    public $tmp_name;

    /**
     * Error code of uploaded file, if any
     *
     * @var int
     */
    public $error;

    /**
     * Size of uploaded file, in bytes
     *
     * @var int
     */
    public $size;

    /**
     * Indicates if the file has been moved out of the temp storage.
     *
     * @var bool
     */
    private $moved = false;

    /**
    *
    * @param string $fieldName Name of uploaded field in HTML form
    * @param string $name Name of uploaded file from client system
    * @param string $type MIME type of uploaded file
    * @param string $tmp_name Full path and filename of temporary uploaded file
    * @param int $error Error code of uploaded file, if any
    * @param int $size Size of uploaded file, in bytes
    * @return UploadHandlerFile
    */
    public function __construct ($fieldName, $name, $type, $tmp_name, $error, $size)
    {
        $this->fieldName = $fieldName;
        $this->name = $name;
        $this->type = $type;
        $this->tmp_name = $tmp_name;
        $this->error = $error;
        $this->size = $size;
    }

    /**
     * Attempts to moves this uploaded file to the given destination folder, automatically using the client-provided filename.
     *
     * @param string $destination Folder to move the file to
     * @param bool $overwrite Optional. Default true. If true, any existing destination file will be overwritten. If false, this will throw UploadHandlerFileMoveExistsException if the destination file exists.
     * @return bool Returns true on success, otherwise false.
     * @throws UploadHandlerFileMoveExistsException If the destination file exists and $overwrite is false.
     */
    public function move ($destination, $overwrite = true)
    {
        //  remove trailing slashes in the destination folder
        $destination = rtrim($destination, '\/');

        return $this->moveAs($destination . '/' . $this->name);
    }

    /**
     * Attempted to move this uploaded file to the given destination folder with the given filename
     *
     * @param $destination Folder to move the file to
     * @param bool $overwrite Optional. Default true. If true, any existing destination file will be overwritten. If false, this will throw UploadHandlerFileMoveExistsException if the destination file exists.
     * @return bool Returns true if the file was moved otherwise false if the file was already moved or if is_uploaded_file check returns false. If a move was attempted but failed an exception will be thrown.
     * @throws UploadHandlerFileMoveExistsException If the destination file exists and $overwrite is false.
     * @throws UploadHandlerFileMoveNotWritableException If the destination file exists and is not writable.
     */
    public function moveAs ($destination, $overwrite = true)
    {
        if ($this->moved || !is_uploaded_file($this->tmp_name)) {
            return false;
        }

        if (file_exists($destination)) {
            if (!$overwrite) {
                throw new UploadHandlerFileMoveExistsException(sprintf(UploadHandler::$i18n['UPLOADHANDLER_ERR_MOVE_EXISTS'], $this->tmp_name, $destination));
            }

            if (!is_writable($destination)) {
                throw new UploadHandlerFileMoveNotWritableException(sprintf(UploadHandler::$i18n['UPLOADHANDLER_ERR_MOVE_NOT_WRITABLE'], $this->tmp_name, $destination));
            }
        }

        $result = @move_uploaded_file($this->tmp_name, $destination);
        if (!$result) {
            // checks are performed above to avoid this but move_uploaded_file can still fail since the calls are not atomic
            throw new UploadHandlerFileMoveNotWritableException(sprintf(UploadHandler::$i18n['UPLOADHANDLER_ERR_MOVE_NOT_WRITABLE'], $this->tmp_name, $destination));
        }

        $this->moved = true;
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Returns the extension of the uploaded file based on the client-side filename. Files with no extensions will return a blank string, files such as ".htaccess" will return "htaccess".
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getExtension ()
    {
        //  reverse the string, find the text before the first (formerly last) dot and return it
        $reversed = strrev($this->name);
        $dot = strpos($reversed, '.', 0);
        if ($dot === false || $dot === 0) {
            //  no dot or dot is at end of filename
            return '';
        }

        //  reverse the extension and return it
        return strrev(substr($reversed, 0, $dot));
    }

    /**
     * Determines if the file was uploaded OK according to the error code.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function getSuccess ()
    {
        return ($this->error === 0);
    }

    /**
     *
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getErrorMessage ()
    {
        $messages = array(
            UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE     => 'UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE',
            UPLOAD_ERR_FORM_SIZE    => 'UPLOAD_ERR_FORM_SIZE',
            UPLOAD_ERR_PARTIAL      => 'UPLOAD_ERR_PARTIAL',
            UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE      => 'UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE',
            UPLOAD_ERR_NO_TMP_DIR   => 'UPLOAD_ERR_NO_TMP_DIR',
            UPLOAD_ERR_CANT_WRITE   => 'UPLOAD_ERR_CANT_WRITE',
            UPLOAD_ERR_EXTENSION    => 'UPLOAD_ERR_EXTENSION',
        );

        if (!isset($messages[$this->error])) {
            return '';
        }

        return sprintf(UploadHandler::$i18n[$messages[$this->error]], $this->fieldName, $this->type, $this->tmp_name, $this->error, $this->size, $this->getExtension());
    }
}

/**
* Generic file upload handler class with temporary file management, exception throwing and language-based error information
*
*/
class UploadHandler {

    /**
     * Whether or not uploaded files have been processed yet.
     *
     * @var bool
     */
    protected static $_processed = false;

    /**
     * Default language text that can be changed by the app using this lib.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    public static $i18n;

    /**
     * Content length specified in the POST request.
     *
     * @var int
     */
    public static $contentLength;

    /**
     * Max post size specified in php.ini stored as a number in bytes
     *
     * @var int
     */
    public static $maxPostSize;

    /**
     * Max post size specified in php.ini stored as a number in bytes
     *
     * @var int
     */
    public static $uploadMaxFilesize;

    /**
     * Max uploadable file size based on max POST size and max upload file size
     *
     * @var int
     */
    public static $maxUploadSize;

    /**
     * Storage for data about files that have been uploaded. Array will contain a set of UploadHandlerFile instances.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    public static $files;

    /**
     * Takes a php.ini-like bytes-size string such as 2M and converts it to a number. G, M and K each represent a unit of 1024 bytes: http://php.net/ini_get
     *
     * @param string $val The value to convert
     * @return int The result in bytes
     */
    public static function iniBytes ($val)
    {
        $val = trim($val);
        $scale = strtolower($val[strlen($val) - 1]);

        $val = intval($val);
        switch ($scale) {
            case 'g':
                $val *= 1024;

            case 'm':
                $val *= 1024;

            case 'k':
                $val *= 1024;
        }

        return $val;
    }

    /**
     * Processes server and $_FILE info relating to uploads to produce usable info. Assigns all gathered data to class variables which are accessible via public methods.
     *
     * @return void
     * @throws UploadHandlerProcessPostSizeException If the posted data size exceeds the maximum post size defined by php configuration
     * @throws UploadHandlerProcessNoInputException If no files were uploaded
     */
    public static function processUploads ()
    {
        if (self::$_processed) {
            return;
        }

        self::$_processed = true;

        self::$files = array();

        if (self::$contentLength >= self::$maxPostSize) {
            //  post length exceeds maximum post length ini directive - impossible for php to parse uploaded files because $_FILES is empty
            throw new UploadHandlerProcessPostSizeException(sprintf(self::$i18n['UPLOADHANDLER_ERR_PROCESS_POST_SIZE'], self::$contentLength, self::$maxPostSize));
        }

        if (empty($_FILES)) {
            //  no files uploaded
            throw new UploadHandlerProcessNoInputException(self::$i18n['UPLOADHANDLER_ERR_PROCESS_NO_INPUT']);
        }

        foreach ($_FILES as $fieldName => $field) {

            if (is_array($field['name'])) {
                //  input field that uses [] in it's name

                self::$files[$fieldName] = array();

                foreach ($field['name'] as $index => $ignoreThisValue) {
                    $name = $field['name'][$index];
                    $type = $field['type'][$index];
                    $tmp_name = $field['tmp_name'][$index];
                    $error = intval($field['error'][$index]);
                    $size = intval($field['size'][$index]);

                    $file = new UploadHandlerFile($fieldName, $name, $type, $tmp_name, $error, $size);

                    self::$files[$fieldName][] = $file;
                }

            } else {
                //  single input field
                $name = $field['name'];
                $type = $field['type'];
                $tmp_name = $field['tmp_name'];
                $error = intval($field['error']);
                $size = intval($field['size']);

                $file = new UploadHandlerFile($fieldName, $name, $type, $tmp_name, $error, $size);

                self::$files[$fieldName] = array($file);
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Returns a flat list of all uploaded files; whether successful or not
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public static function getAllFiles ()
    {
        self::processUploads();

        $return = array();
        foreach (self::$files as $field => $files) {
            foreach ($files as $file) {
                $return[] = $file;
            }
        }
        return $return;
    }

    /**
     * Returns only a list of files that were uploaded successfully
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public static function getUploadedFiles ()
    {
        self::processUploads();

        $return = array();
        foreach (self::$files as $field => $files) {
            foreach ($files as $file) {
                if ($file->getSuccess()) {
                    $return[] = $file;
                }
            }
        }
        return $return;
    }

    /**
     * Returns only a list of files that were not uploaded successfully
     *
     * @param bool $includeEmpty Optional. Default false. Set to true to include empty file upload fields as errors.
     * @return array
     */
    public static function getErrorFiles ($includeEmpty = false)
    {
        self::processUploads();

        $return = array();
        foreach (self::$files as $field => $files) {
            foreach ($files as $file) {
                if (!$includeEmpty && $file->error == UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE) {
                    continue;
                }

                if (!$file->getSuccess()) {
                    $return[] = $file;
                }
            }
        }
        return $return;
    }
}

//  statically set default language vars - an app that needs to customize messages can do so after including this class (only needs to happen once)

UploadHandler::$i18n = array(
    'UPLOADHANDLER_ERR_PROCESS_POST_SIZE'   => 'POST size of %1$d bytes exceeds the limit set in php.ini#post_max_size of %2$d bytes.',
    'UPLOADHANDLER_ERR_PROCESS_NO_INPUT'    => 'No file input fields were detected in the POST request.',
    'UPLOADHANDLER_ERR_MOVE_EXISTS'         => 'Could not move uploaded file "%1$s" to "%2$s" as the destination file already exists and the overwrite option was not set.',
    'UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE'                   => 'The uploaded file exceeds the upload_max_filesize directive in php.ini.',
    'UPLOAD_ERR_FORM_SIZE'                  => 'The uploaded file exceeds the MAX_FILE_SIZE directive that was specified in the HTML form.',
    'UPLOAD_ERR_PARTIAL'                    => 'The uploaded file was only partially uploaded.',
    'UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE'                    => 'No file was uploaded.',
    'UPLOAD_ERR_NO_TMP_DIR'                 => 'Missing a temporary folder.',
    'UPLOAD_ERR_CANT_WRITE'                 => 'Failed to write file to disk.',
    'UPLOAD_ERR_EXTENSION'                  => 'File upload stopped by extension.',
    'UPLOADHANDLER_ERR_MOVE_NOT_WRITABLE'   => 'File not writable.'
);

//  statically set some values that do not change throughout the lifetime of a request

UploadHandler::$contentLength = (int)@$_SERVER['CONTENT_LENGTH'];
UploadHandler::$maxPostSize = UploadHandler::iniBytes(ini_get('post_max_size'));

// store this for informational purposes only - php upload support will internally deny uploads which are over this size but client-side code can use this to advise of file size limits
UploadHandler::$uploadMaxFilesize = UploadHandler::iniBytes(ini_get('upload_max_filesize'));

// the lowest of both maxPostSize and uploadMaxFile size determines the maximum size of a single file upload (may not be accurate to the byte since there's some POST overhead if max POST size happens to be smaller than max file size)
UploadHandler::$maxUploadSize = min(UploadHandler::$uploadMaxFilesize, UploadHandler::$maxPostSize);
```

Comment: Its solve the problem but generates other problems Can you plz give me your mail address so i can send you all info

Comment: Ok i send the files with issues.

Comment: Hi, Ahmed plz check your mail ... i send you the php files to trouble shoot the logo upload error. ...